# Django dropdown filter queryset with FilterView

Tags: django

I want to filter apartments by selecting subcity field in a dropdown in my django app. I'm using django-filters and django-bootstrap-form. But the dropdown does not populate with database querysets. How can I make the dropdown work?

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry,Point
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
import datetime
from leaflet.forms.widgets import LeafletWidget
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geo_models


# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

geos_pnt=Point(4314498.56, 1003834.600,srid=3857)
#pnt=GEOSGeometry('POINT(4314498.56, 1003834.600)').wkt

class Apartment(models.Model):
    ADKT='Addis Ketema'
    AKLT='Akaki-Kality'
    ARDA= 'Arada'
    BOLE='Bole'
    GLLE='Gulele'
    KLFE='Kolfe-Keranio'
    KIRK='Kirkos'
    LDTA='Lideta'
    YEKA='Yeka'
    NFSL='Nefas Silk-Lafto'
    SUBCITY_CHOICES = [
    (ADKT, 'Addis Ketema'), 
    (AKLT, 'Akaki-Kality'), 
    (ARDA, 'Arada'), 
    (BOLE, 'Bole'), 
    (GLLE, 'Gulele'),
    (KLFE, 'Kolfe-Keranio'), 
    (KIRK,'Kirkos'),
    (LDTA, 'Lideta'), 
    (NFSL, 'Nefas Silk-Lafto'), 
    (YEKA, 'Yeka')]

    apt_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True,editable=True)
    geom = geo_models.PointField(null=True)
    apt_area = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    no_bedrooms = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    apt_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    apt_subcity = models.CharField(default='KIRK',choices=SUBCITY_CHOICES,max_length=30,null=True)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    sites =models.ManyToManyField(Site)

    
    
    
    #change points from apt_rent_db to kml
    def pointkml(self):
        points = Apartment.objects.kml()
        return render("placemarks.kml", {'places': points})
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rent_app:apartment-listing', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #self.Latitude = self..y
        #self.Longitude = self.location.x

        self.slug = slugify(self.apt_id)
          

        super(Apartment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
       # order of drop-down list items
       verbose_name = ("Apartment")
       verbose_name_plural = ("Apartments")
       ordering = ('apt_cost',)
       app_label = 'rent_app'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.apt_id

    
    @property
    def picture_url(self):
        return self.picture.url


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

views.py:

```
  class ApartmentFilterView(FilterView):
    model = Apartment
    context_object_name = 'apartments'
    filter_class = ApartmentFilter
```

filters.py:
import django_filters
from .models import Apartment,UserProfile

```
class ApartmentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ADKT = 'Addis Ketema'
    AKLT = 'Akaki-Kality'
    ARDA = 'Arada'
    BOLE = 'Bole'
    GLLE = 'Gulele'
    KLFE = 'Kolfe-Keranio'
    KIRK = 'Kirkos'
    LDTA = 'Lideta'
    YEKA = 'Yeka'
    NFSL = 'Nefas Silk-Lafto'
    SUBCITY_CHOICES = [
        (ADKT, 'Addis Ketema'),
        (AKLT, 'Akaki-Kality'),
        (ARDA, 'Arada'),
        (BOLE, 'Bole'),
        (GLLE, 'Gulele'),
        (KLFE, 'Kolfe-Keranio'),
        (KIRK, 'Kirkos'),
        (LDTA, 'Lideta'),
        (NFSL, 'Nefas Silk-Lafto'),
        (YEKA, 'Yeka')]

    ordering = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(label='Ordering',subcity_choices=SUBCITY_CHOICES, method='filter_by_ordering')

    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = {

            'apt_cost': ['lte'],
            #'apt_dist': ['lt'],
            'apt_subcity': ['icontains'],

        }
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block title %} የተገኙ ቤቶች | Apartment List {% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
{{obj.apt_id}} - Birr {{obj.apt_cost}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I do not know *django-filter* but it looks like you need any way a `Meta` subclass to define the model on which the filter is bases, as presented in the [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-filter)

Comment: @Christophe I updated the filters.py but the template isn't showing dropdown queryset items (apartment.subcity)

Comment: Could you please share your model's definition?

Comment: @Christophe I added models.py

Comment: OK, so I guess you've defined views to create / update apartments, where you uses these filter: is there any other reason why you define such a filter in your app? I'm just talking about `Apartment` object

Comment: @Christophe I want to filter Apartments by subcity, so that when I user dropdown and selects the subcities, it filters them.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be listed in the Meta class.

```
class yourfilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = your_model
```

Comment: I have updated my filters.py to include the class Meta. However, the template is not rendering the queryset items ( apartment.subcity). The dropdown should show the subcities and filter based on selection.